# What can we do with the dataset that 98 percent of the columns are null values?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, prediction, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I want to predict down time of the servers before it happens. To achive this aim, I collected many data from different data sources.

One of the data sources is metric data which contain cpu-time, cpu-percentage, memory-usage, etc. However, values of the columns in this dataset are null. I mean 98% of the many columns are null.

What kind of data preperation technique can be used to prepere the data before apply it to a prediction algorithm.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Since data is the **"Fuel"** for machine learning when you say 98% of the data is missing meaning only 2% of data available then I don't think you can go much further with this. Because even if you do succeed to prep the missing data its again just a prediction and adjustments on the missing data but not the actual data itself. So the Model built upon this type of data is going to fail to predict any thing closer to reality as it was built on 98% of assumption data. `You can correct me if I am wrong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were in your situation my first option would be to ignore this data source. There is too much missing data to be a relevant source of information for any ML algorithm.

That being said, if you still want to use this source of data, you will have to fill the gaps. Infer the missing data with only 2% of available data is hardly possible, but when you are speaking of more than 90% of missing data, I would advise to have a look at Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization).

A few versions of this algorithm are [implemeted in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/vignettes/NMF-vignette.pdf), also to have better results in inferring such a big amount of missing data you could read [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/mei17a/mei17a.pdf) which uses times series information -which could be your case- with NMF to get better results. I ran some tests up to 95% of missing data and results were not so bad, hence, as discussed earlier, you could discard some of your data to have only 80% or 90% of missing data, then apply NMF for times series.

Answer (score 1):

Normally various data imputation techniques can be applied, but in the case of 98% null values, I don't think this would be a correct approach, you are going to infer the empty data from just 2% available information; this would generate an enormous amount of bias in your data. I would go for such an option: Sort your rows such in descending order, such that the rows with the largest number of non-null columns come first. Then determine a cutoff from the beginning of the sorted list of rows, such that, for example, only 20% of the data missing in the selected subset of the data. Then apply data imputation. But of course, this assumes that you will have enough number of data points (rows) after determining this cutoff, which you may not have and the data is not missing at random for each row (if data is missing at random for each row, you cannot use this sorting method at all).

In any case, I can hardly see a concrete way of getting a meaningful model built by using such a high amount of missing data.

Answer (score 0):

First, there can be many reasons why your data are null, like, it was not planed to get those data in the previous project version, then you upgrade it but it is not retroactive so you only have access to the data from the new version, meaning the 2% are fine data but represent nothing compared to total volume cause the new version is just up since X days; etc.

ANYWAY

Even if you have only 2% of non-null data, it does not really matters, what does matter is "how many data represent those 2%" ? If it is 2% of 5 billions, then it is enough to take "just" the 2% of non-null as training data and ignore the others!

Now, if the 2% represents just few data, then I really advise you to NOT fill the null values with them, because it will create enormous bias, furthermore, it means your actual process is not ready for implementing machine learning project => Just adapt to get more data.